# Better alternative to Hold/ReleaseHold for postfix application of Monitor

Tags: functions, syntax, hold

Trying to `Monitor` a process using the postfix notation, as in

```
Table[Pause[n/10], {n, 5}] // Monitor[#, n] &
```

fails: the argument `Table[Pause[n/10], {n, 5}]` is evaluated before being passed to the pure function `Monitor[#,n]&` because that function does not have the attribute `HoldAll` like `Monitor` itself.

An option is to `Hold` explicitly and release the hold inside the pure function:

```
Table[Pause[n/10], {n, 5}] // Hold // Monitor[ReleaseHold[#], n] &
```

Is there a simpler/cleaner/shorter way?  Obviously `Monitor[Table[...],n]` works, but I'd rather separate the code from the monitoring.

Comment: I tend to use an infix version `Table[...] ~Monitor~ n`.

Comment: Ah, I was wrong to insist on postfix.  The infix notation is great, I'll use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Unevaluated`

```
Unevaluated@Table[Pause[n/10], {n, 5}] // Monitor[#, n] &
```

The neater way will be to use the infix version as suggested by wxffles in the comments, but your question specifically asked for postfix so...
For completeness, here it is

```
Table[Pause[n/10], {n, 5}] ~Monitor~ n
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your `Monitor` call in a `Function` object endowed with a holding attribute:

```
Table[Pause[n/10], {n, 10}] // Function[{input}, Monitor[input, n], HoldAll]
```

This will work as though you had wrapped `Monitor` around your `Table`.

[image]